# SQLalchemy load only id of joined table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm working on optimizing our queries with SQLalchemy and I have a case where I have lets say a User class with a relationship to a Country class via the country field. For optimization purposes when I fetch a User, I would like the country field to be filled with the id of the Country. Is there a way to achieve this in SQLAlchemy? The loading strategies described here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html are not covering the scenario. I need something like noload('*') but fetching the id instead of None

Comment: Uh, that's the default behavior. When you query a model, all fields are loaded, *including foreign keys* like the country column.

Comment: I have 2 fields right now on my model _country_id (_country_id = Column("country_id", Integer, ForeignKey('countries.id'))) and also country = relationship("Country"). I would like to do a query and when i ask it to joinedload("country") to fetch the whole object and when not to fill the country field with the id. I'm dynamically getting these values and that moment my code is not aware of the _country_id field. not sure if that makes sense

Comment: If you only want to load `id` on `country` you can use [`load_only`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only), but why not just access `_country_id` instead?

Comment: @valanto did you find a solution? I actually hit a very similar problem, but in my case instead of the relationship being loaded, I want it to be lazy loaded per attribute access. eg when somebody does "user.country", I want it to only issue "select id from country where user_id=?", and all further attributes to be lazy loaded per access.